# Creating Files/Reading Files with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, file, io

I have been looking for *quite a while* for a way to **Create/Write/Read** Files, I almost had it done on my own when I came across "*Access to* **'File Directory'** *Denied*" Meaning I can't create a file at the specified location, that of being *program files* but It prompts me with the same message just trying to access the **C Drive**. I need a simple way to Create a file and write to it, then to later read the file as arrays of data, That of being a line in *If possible* a .dat file. Here is what I have tried:

```
IO.File.Create("C:\Program Files\CompanyName\ProgramName\ProgramType\Data")
```

But that is to create my directory, This is what I did to create my .dat file

```
IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Program Files\CompanyName\ProgramName\ProgramType\Data\data.dat", String.Join("|", New String() {NameTBox.Text}))
```

Then this is what I tried to read the file:

```
        Dim values() As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Program Files\CompanyName\ProgramName\ProgramType\Data\data.dat").Split("|"c)
        NameTBox.Text = values(0)
        NameLabel.Text = values(0) + "!"
```

It doesn't work for me and I get an exception, I surrounded the read and creates with try's and catches and no exceptions, but no files either.

I am using **Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express** Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Have you tried with a folder that doesn't require administrative privileges to write to?

Comment: Well, Even the C Drive isn't allowing me access, so I can't access any file really... But It is supposed to be a professional-ish program so I need it in a secure folder, Thanks though!

Comment: Non administrators don't have write access to the root of the drive - perhaps try with your desktop, or my documents to at least rule out file/directory access permissions

Comment: Well, while that may be it, I need my program to access that area, **even** if they are not an administrator so that it can properly install it, Also I am the administrator, and am signed into it, so that couldn't be the issue, am I correct?

Comment: Might be worth reading up on UAC.